# What are the cases we should use stride which is not 1?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I read a lot of tutorials and view some posts which used `CNN` with, `stride` 1 or `stride` 2 (for down sampling).

But I didn't saw any examples with `stride` of length 3 or above.

- Is there any sense to use strides that bigger than 2 ?
- Do you have any examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

larger strides mean you are effectively gaining more speed/using less memory footprint at the expense of losing much more valuable information that can ultimately influence your accuracy.

Also, note that larger strides can also be used when you want to take advantage of the (usually large) input at hand in your model and do the downsampling while the learning process is underway as opposed to resizing the images to much smaller dimensions and starting off using more smaller strides.

apart from this, refrain from using large strides throughout the network blindly as it hinders your model's learning capacity.

There is always a cost/benefit scenario associated with actions like this. It's up to
you, the architecture designer, that based on the requirements at hand, to make the call to do what or which compromises to make.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the size of your filter.
The choice is a compromise between speed and accuracy.